# Bitwise XOR operation on UTF-8 string gives non UTF-8 output

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, encryption, xor

I've built a basic XOR encryption program, which encrypts a .txt file using a key. It works fine, but I'd like for the file to only contain UTF-8 characters even after encryption. At the moment, I get output like this when viewed in a text editor:

```
1GCh!/39hpj1GCCh
hpj1GjjCCCh!/3hpj~yGCC7fGGCChhpj1GjjCCCh!/3hpj~xGCC7fGGCChhpj1GjjCCCh!/3hpj~{GCC7fGGCChhpj1GjjCCCh!/3hpjyrGCC7fGGCChhpj1GjjCCCh!/3hpjyGCC7fGGCChhpj1GjjCCCh!/3hpjy|GCC7fGGCCh
hpj1GjjCCCh!/3hpjy}GCC7fGGCCh
hpj1GjjCCCh!/3hpj~zGCC7fGGCChhpj1GjjCCCh!/3hpjysGCC7fGGCChhpj1GjjCCCh!/3hpj{~GCC7fGGCChhpj1GjjCCCh!/3hpj{GCC7fGGCCh
hpj1GjjCCCh!/3hpj{|GCC7fGGCChhpj1GjjCCCh!/3hpj{}GCC7fGGCChhpj1GjjCCCh!/3hpjh=hGCC7fGGCChhpj1GjjCCCh!/3hpjh+hGCC7fGGCChhpj1GjjCCCh!/3hpjh9hGCC7fGGCCh
hpj1GjjCCCh!/3hpjh.hGCC7GC7G7G
```

There are many artifacts here that I think are the result of non-UTF characters.

Is it possible to perform a bitwise XOR operation to yield UTF characters only?

For reference, here is my crypt function:

```
static std::string XORCrypt(std::string key, std::string data) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i != data.size(); i++) {
        data[i] ^= key[i % key.size()];
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: not if you xor all the bits, no. You could try xoring the string and then base_64-encoding it.

Comment: Thanks - do you know if there's a certain function or type I would be after here? I'm fairly new to this area and any more specific advice would be fantastic.

Comment: Why would you want to view an encrypted file in a text editor in the first place? Expecting an encrypted UTF-8 file to be another UTF-8 file is like expecting an encrypted Shakespeare's sonnet to be another Shakespeare's sonnet.

Comment: It's because I have [a plugin for Atom](https://atom.io/packages/selectxor) that can quickly encode and decode XOR encrypted text files which is useful to me for my project. It doesn't work with my encoded files though since they're not UTF encoded. It's for convenience and I'm not at all concerned about security. I just want the files to be obfuscated for project-related non-security reasons.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just restrict the changed bits to the lowest 3 bits. That's the only bit zone in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) that is arbitrary for all valid UTF-8 code units.

You could run your key through an expander function to lengthen it to meet that requirement.

---

And, I think we'd all feel more comfortable if you change the wording from "encryption" to "obfuscation."

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. Each byte in the UTF-8 sequence has some fixed bits and some that depend on the character. If the byte has the high bit 0 then it is an ASCII character and you could imagine only xor-ing the lower 7 bit (*), but that would reveal which characters were ASCII in the original which isn't good. If you change the high bit you break UTF-8 encoding completely.

In addition a simple xor-encryption is broken if you can send in one known plain-text.

The simple advise is to not make your own encryption.

(*) And similarly, but more complicated for the ones with high bit set.

Answer (score 0):

UTF8 has a variable character length, which means it defines certain byte sequences (1, 2 or more bytes) as some specific characters. There are many possible combination of bytes but only a subset of those is valid, this subset can be seen for example [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de). What happens here is you are changing only a single byte from that sequence at a time. This may alter not only a single character but many more following it as the sequences now become misaligned. In addition to that you might generate something which is not even present in the table at all. Therefore if You want to encrypt UTF8 text and the cryptogram has to be UTF8 readable you need to have logic in place that recognises UTF characters and alters them in some predictable way.